# TypeOrm not able to recognize the entities via directory path

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Im using typeorm with nestjs and postgreSql and trying to load the entities via the datasource options object which gets passed in the useFactory async function inside the typeorm module like

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({ useFactory: () => (datasourceOptions) })],
})
```

this dataSourceOptions obejct is in a separate file containing the key value pairs of options and values repsectively. i wanted to pass typeorm to check and recognize the entities via the glob pattern

```
 entities: [
        join(__dirname, "../**/*entity{.ts,.js}")
    ],
```

like this , i have tried to test it with different patterns still i cant get it to work and i remember it used to work earlier with these patterns automatically registering the entities , now for a workaround i manually put in the entities instead of the pattern . how do i solve it so that all the entities get regitered without me having to entering the entity names manually one by one like

```
entities: [User, Conversation,Room, ],
```

i tried using different glob patterns and even the verified ones which used to work earlier but none are working right now , i dont know if thats because of some recent changes in the typeorm datasource options .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rolled back to 0.3.11 and it worked.

The problem is related to the paths in Windows:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9766

It seems that the problem lies in minor changes (0.3.12).

Install:

```
"typeorm": "0.3.11"
```

Not:

```
"typeorm": "^0.3.11",
"typeorm": "^0.3.12",
"typeorm": "0.3.12",
```

Comment: typeOrm 0.3.13 just got released and i tested with it the entities are getting registered properly and now the migrations are also working fine as well

Comment: Thanks guy. I just switch to Win11. and I can confirm that version 0.3.12 is the root cause of this problem

Answer (score 2):

This work for me,

```
entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js'],
```

My folder structure:

```
src
  └── modules
      └── user
          ├── user.controller.ts
          ├── user.entity.ts
          ├── user.module.ts
          └── user.service.ts
```

Comment: Write what version of typeorm you use and which OS?

Comment: I use linux kali OS and  "typeorm": "^0.3.12"

Comment: It turns out, indeed, the problem is only in Windows for typeorm 0.3.12

Comment: My solution can work well with Windows OS

Comment: Hope our answers help someone :)

Comment: so youre saying this issue exists only with the particular typeorm 0.3.12 version???

Comment: bhiasab upvote krdo reputation mil jaegi , (please upvote i need reputation)

Comment: Thanks guy. I just switch to Win11. and I can confirm that version 0.3.12 is the root cause of this problem